# Proving dense subset in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Could anyone help with the following basic metric space problem?

Show that $A$ is dense in $X$ if and only if the only closed set containing $A$ is $X$.

I know the general idea is to take Cauchy sequence in $A$, then show the limit of the sequence can be found within the same space. 
By definition,if we take $A\subseteq X$ be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$. Then $A$ is said to be dense in $X$ if $\bar{A}=X$...

Please help making more precise.

Comment: The closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$.  If $X$ is the only closed set containing $A$ then necessarily $\bar A=X$.  That gives you $\Leftarrow$

Comment: There is no reason to consider Cauchy sequences at all. The details of the proof will depend on exactly how you’ve defined the notion of ‘$A$ is dense in $X$’. The two most common definitions are that $\operatorname{cl}A=X$, in which case the result is trivial, and that whenever $U\subseteq X$ is open and non-empty, then $U\cap A\ne\varnothing$, in which case you’ll have to do a little work. Since you’re working in a metric setting, someone *might* have defined it to mean that every point of $X$ is the limit of a sequence of points of $A$, though that would be very bad pædagogy.

Comment: @Brian. Yes you are absolutely correct. But I use Cauchy sequences because I am interested in knowing how to prove something is dense in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant the only closed set **in $X$** that contains $A$ is $X$.

If  $A$ is dense in $X$ then the closure of $A$ is $X$. By the definition of closure of $A$, the smallest closed set containing $A$ is $X$. Let $B \subseteq X$ such that $B$ contains $A$. Then $B$ must contain $X$, so $X \subseteq B$ hence $B = X$.

The other direction is given in the comments.

Comment: when you say $B$ contains $A$, do you mean $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: @math101 Yes, that is what I meant.